# Filtering your LINQ to XML query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\myfile.xml");

List<Tag> list = new List<Tag>();

foreach (var tag in xdoc.Descendants("META"))

{

string name = tag.Attribute("name").Value;

string value = tag.Element("value").Value;

list.Add(new Tag { Name = name, Value = value, Score = score, Key = key });

}
```

but I need to only get the META elements under the element ARTICLE.

Can I add this to the linq query somehow?

The xml looks similar to this:

```
<DOCUMENT>
  <META name="aaa"/>
  <ARTICLE>
   <META name="bbb" value="708" score="0.58" key="6008"/>
  </ARTICLE>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Thanks for any suggestions

In the end I need to do something like the following:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(tr);
var meta = from el in xdoc.Descendants("ARTICLE").Elements("META")
where (string) el.Attribute("name") == "RAW"
select el;

List<Tag> list = new List<Tag>();
foreach (var tag in meta)
{
 string name = tag.Attribute("name").Value;
 string value = tag.Attribute("value").Value;
 string score = tag.Attribute("score").Value;
 string key = tag.Attribute("key").Value;

list.Add(new Tag { Name = name, Value = value, Score = score, Key = key });
}
```

The reason for this is that I needed to match the attribute where the name was equal to RAW.

Please correct me if there's a better way to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find them anywhere in the document, use `xdoc.Descendants("ARTICLE")` to find all the `ARTICLE` elements, and then `Elements("META")` from there to find all the direct `META` children elements.

In addition, you can perform the projection and the conversion to a list in the same query:

```
var list = xdoc.Descendants("ARTICLE")
               .Elements("META")
               .Select(x => new Tag { Name = (string) x.Attribute("name"),
                                      Value = (string) x.Attribute("value"),
                                      Key = key })
               .ToList();
```